# Valgrind reporting possible stack overflow - what does it mean?

Tags: c, memory, out-of-memory, bit

When I run my C program file using valgrind, I get the following error and segmentation fault. What does it mean?

I got this error due to recursive call of one function more deep

i allocated 9684173 bytes for character pointer
i malloc successfully and i got segmentation fault in Recursivly call of one funcation deeply. so any solution of this??

```
==3100== Stack overflow in thread 1: can't grow stack to 0x7fe801ff8
==3100== 
==3100== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==3100==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x7FE801FF8
==3100==    at 0x4014D8: huffman_decoding (filebits.c:471)
==3100==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==3100==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==3100==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==3100==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==3100==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==3100== Stack overflow in thread 1: can't grow stack to 0x7fe801ff0
==3100== 
==3100== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==3100==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x7FE801FF0
==3100==    at 0x4A2269F: _vgnU_freeres (vg_preloaded.c:58)
==3100==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==3100==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==3100==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==3100==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==3100==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==3100== 
==3100== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3100==     in use at exit: 22,490,801 bytes in 179 blocks
==3100==   total heap usage: 179 allocs, 0 frees, 22,490,801 bytes allocated
==3100== 
==3100== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3100==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3100==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3100==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3100==    still reachable: 22,490,801 bytes in 179 blocks
==3100==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3100== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==3100== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==3100== 
==3100== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3100== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==3100== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: We're gonna need to see some code to be able to help.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams read now

Comment: i got solution of this question

Answer (score 2):

You're either trying to allocate too much on the stack or calling a recursive function too deep.

Since you mention "i want to compress one big file which size is 12 MB" I have a strong feeling you're trying to allocate 12M on the stack.

Comment: trying to calling a recursive funcation too deep

Comment: I got this error due to recursive call of one funcation more deep

i allocated 9684173 bytes for character pointer i done successfully and i go segmentation fault in Recursivly call of one funcation deeply. so any solution of this??

Answer (score 0):

This message means that you are trying to allocate a lot of data in your stack, to solve this issue try to free stack as possobile or you have to increase your stack size using ulimit commands

> ulimit -s new_size

or using the function "setrlimit" in C.

Of course I don't recommend so, if you will use big stack size, use malloc instead.

Comment: how can i know my current stack maximux size?

Comment: using "ulimit -s" or using getrlimit function

Comment: eep! why would you make such a larger stack? put the file content in allocated memory not on the stack, that's just horrid programming practice.  Typically  Linux system sets the soft limit of stack to 8192 kbytes,  and that should be sufficient for all call depths in a nominal program.

Comment: @ahm.madkour we can directly set the stack size?

Comment: @ahm.madkour how we can move file content to allocated memory from stack

Comment: @Sam_k lookup heap allocation if you haven't already; that's where large allocations should go - http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-the-functions-malloc-and-free

Comment: @Ahmed Masud I didn't mean creating 12M stack, of course one should never do that.